# Lists/Dictionaries from function not returned

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython

I'm trying to write a script in Python using BioPython that reads a FASTA file and generates a list of the raw DNA sequences as entries.

As this code will be used by many other scripts I will be writing, I want the function for this purpose to be in a separate Python file, which I can import at the start of every other script I write. The script containing the function I am currently calling is as so:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
def read_fasta(dna):
    genome = []
    for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(dna, "fasta"):
        genome.append(str(seq_record.seq))
    return genome
```

When I call this function in Python from cmd, the function works and reads the files generating the list as I wish. However, if I try to access the list `genome` again, I get an `Traceback | NameError: name 'genome' not defined` error.

Can somebody explain why this is happening, even thought I have put the `return genome` statement? And what I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: can you show stack trace?

Comment: Can you show the script where you are using this function with the stacktrace?

Comment: Where are you calling it?  When you call it, it returns the *value*, it doesn't create a variable called `genome`.  You have to do something with the returned value.

Comment: In cmd, I am calling it by saying:
from Bio_FASTA import *

read_fasta("pcr_template.fasta")

How should I assign a variable to genome / do something with it? Thanks!

Comment: `genome = read_fasta("pcr_template.fasta")`. Although this 'global' `genome` variable you are creating doesn't have anything in common with the 'local' `genome` variable, except the name, (the 'local' `genome` exists only while `read_fasta` function isn't finished), it is better to name it something else, for example `result = read_fasta("pcr_template.fasta")`. Now when you try to acces the `result` variable, you will have `genome` list.

Comment: @Reloader I feel a bit stupid now lol, that should have been quite obvious to me! Thank you for your help!!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`genome` is in the local scope of the function, so it is not visible from the "outside". You should assign result of `read_fasta` function to some variable in order to access the returned result of the function. For example:

`new_variable = read_fasta("pcr_template.fasta")`

And it is read - let the `new_variable` be assigned to the result of the function `read_fasta` with `"pcr_template.fasta"` as argument.

Now the `genome` (or anything that your function has returned) is accessed simply by accessing `new_variable`.